# What does "Medikamentenversuche" mean or refer to?

Tags: german-to-english

What does "Medikamentenversuche" mean or refer to? Google Translate makes it out be drug trial, but it seems to refer to a specific incident.

Edited addition:

A Google search of the word brought up loads of stories about a series of unpleasant drug tests on orphans and similar trials, rather than any normal stories thus my concern that this word meant something different from the literal translation.

Comment: When I feed “Medikamentenversuche“ to google translate, it spits out “drug tests”. What did you try?

Comment: Why do you have the impression this refers to a  specific incident?

Comment: No context = no good answer. Your call.

Comment: What @tofro said. Most likely *this* will be about sth like Mengele…, *some* historical event(s)? Anyway. A specific incident would be much easier to explain if we are given some specifics, that is context. Please provide such with an [edit].

Comment: Please reconsider your close votes now that the question was edited.

Comment: You searched for the word after you came across it. I thought the most revealing context would be to know where you came across that word?

Comment: Ein spezielles Fußballspiel heißt immer noch Fußballspiel, ein besonderes Essen bleibt Essen. Wenn der Kontext einen spezieller Versuch nahelegt, dann kommt das vom Kontext.

Comment: @Philipp I am not a native speaker, but as far I know, "versuch" is used in the meaning of "try", but not in the meaning of "test". You may know it better. :-)

Comment: @Philipp  This depens again on context. *Versuch* is in everyday contexts usually like *try*, but e.g. in a laboratory what usually is called *Reagenzglas* can also be called *Versuchsröhrchen* (a little bit old-fashioned, though), just as an example.

Answer (score 2):

It is often used for drug trials especially with humans for research purposes which are not officially allowed. There are a couple of scandals in German history where companies and even hospitals or doctors have been involved to test special drugs before official release. There are very strict rules about testing so sometimes companies try to bypass very expensive testing procedures.

However it does not mean necessarily it is used with this problematic context in mind, so it might be used also simply for drug trials in an official way and a lot of people might not think of it as a bad thing.

Additionally there are following terms related:

**Menschenversuche**: which means trials with humans but with broader meaning including surgery trials and other treatments, this is really an evil word, also Nazis have done this in Konzentrationslager.

**Tierversuche**: which means drug trials with animals which does not have this bad meaning by default.

Comment: A similar word to Tierversuch is Menschenversuch. Feeling that both those terms *might* be used for legitimate research, Medikamentenversuch seems overwhelmingly exclusive for unethical and illegal activities?

Comment: Wörter sind nicht böse, auch nicht wenn sie böses beschreiben. Medikamentenversuche finden *notwendigerweise* vor der Zulassung statt; man will schließlich nichts zulassen, was nicht getestet wurde. Tests zu umgehen erscheint daher auch nicht als rationales Vorgehen, denn ohne Tests gibt es ja keine Zulassung (außer für Homöopathica). Der ganze erste Absatz ist Murks.

Comment: Nun, es wundert mich nicht, dass so Menschenversuche häufiger gefunden werden. Sicher findet man auch das Wort Messer häufiger mit Körperverletzung assoziiert, als mit Gemüseschneiden, obwohl viele Menschen täglich Gemüse schneiden. Deine Methode taugt nix.

Comment: Von Tierversuchen spricht man übrigens auch, wenn Kosmetika an Tieren getestet werden. Außerdem kann man die Auswirkung von Beschleunigung oder beliebige andere Sachverhalte mit Menschen oder Tieren testen, und dies entsprechend bezeichnen.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with that term that prohibits its general usage for translating *drug trial* to German.

**1. Both compounds are put in plural**
This implies there are more than one drug tested. Any serial testing on human beings would however be unethical.

**2. It is close to *Tierversuche* or *Menschenversuche***
Again any such serial tests on human beings are highly unethical.

**3. It is a *Versuch* where trial is also a companion of error**
Such an inherent error is not what people accept.

It is for the above reasons why the term *Medikamentenversuche* may have been chosen for inhuman practices rather than for ethical correct studies.

Much better terms for drug trials that are in common use for various contexts are e.g.:

> Klinische Studie, Arzneimitteltests, Pharmaforschung, ...

Comment: Unethisch wäre es, Medikamente ungetestet auf die Menschheit loszulassen. Unethisch ist es, die Menschen nicht über den Testcharakter aufzuklären bzw. zu Testen, ohne das Einverständnis einzuholen und nach bestem Wissen und Gewissen über die Gefahren aufzuklären. Das gleiche gilt für Menschenversuche. Organtransplantationen etwa hat man zuerst theoretisch durchgespielt, dann an Tieren versucht, und sie sind bei den ersten Menschen natürlich Versuche, ob es funktioniert, Tests.

Comment: Seltsam nur, dass bei WP -versuche als der offizielle Begriff benutzt wird. Siehe meinen Kommentar zur Alt-Antwort: woher diese negative Konnotation? – Imho rollst du hier die Antwort bisher von der falschen Seite her auf. Der erste Absatz der Frage bleibt etwas unterbelichtet?

Comment: I think it's not so much how "drug trial" is *not* ideally translated into German but how MedVrs. is properly translated in all its nuances into English (or explained in that language). It's further not so much the serial trials things that is unethical. It is unethical that unapproved trials without informed consent were carried out repeatedly or routinely, when the word '-versuche' is mostly used.

Comment: @LangLangC: wenn Du mit WP Wikipedia meinst, dann kann ich dort "Medikamentenversuche" nicht als offiziellen Begriff finden. URL? Auch Versuche **mit Einverständnis** können unethisch sein, das ist leider nicht so einfach. Für eine genaue Übersetzung ins Englische sind wir hier nicht zuständig.

Comment: Yep. [Menschenversuch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menschenversuch). Hier geht es aber um Sprachverwendung und warum zur Erklärung von MV in anderer Sprache eine Einwortübersetzung nicht ausreichend ist. An den Kommentaren von user unknown sieht man ja, dass "klinische Studien" auch als Menschen/Medikamentenversuch notwendig sind, wenn aber in der Zeitung von -versuchen die Rede ist anscheinend fast immer die Skandale gemeint sind, die wissenschaftlich notwendigen und korrekt durchgeführten aber selten so bezeichnet werden.

Answer (score 0):

Lacking a concrete example in the question that clearly gives the original context for (a one time) usage, this answer is supplementing the other answers along the findings a general net search for this specific word and its usage reveals.

Literally, a *Medikamentenversuch* is a neutral word describing a clinical drug trial, also and especially in humans.

These trials are in principle: necessary for approval of a drug, now strongly regulated, with oversight from ethics commissions for example, tightly controlled for adverse outcomes, and ended prematurely if necessary.

In actual usage, most commonly found in search results, this compound word is constructed and used like the category parent word *[Menschenversuch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menschenversuch)* (according to Wikipedia: ~"[Human subject research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_subject_research)") Both those *-versuche* are originally *not* describing anything unethical or illegal. Although both are neutral in their original meaning they are overwhelmingly used to describe violations of ethical research standards. That means drug trials where for example no informed consent was given, the dangers involved in every human trial were obviously too high, test subjects were tested to their limits and beyond etc. Sometimes severe side effects, among them them simple death were commonly accepted – by those conducting the trials (Example: [Nazi human experimentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazi_human_experimentation)). In [hindsight](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/feuilleton/menschenversuche-die-grausamkeit-im-dienst-der-wissenschaft-1669912.html), or when these deeds came to the light of the public *these type* of trials are almost universally condemned and reported as major scandals in medicine in recent years. In such cases, most writers seem to exclusively choose *Menschenversuche* or *Medikamentenversuche* to name and blame the experiments, whereas constructions like *klinische Studien* or *Versuche am Menschen* are chosen if they talk about proper trials, conducted according to accepted standards.

This narrower and strongly negatively connotated meaning in actual usage can be shown in several ways:

If you use an evil search engine and look for "Medikamentenversuche", or "Menschenversuche", then it displays almost exclusively scandals in medicine and reports relating to trials of a different kind: court trials, sentences and so on. Again: it seems that "klinische Studien", "Versuche am Menschen" are used to report legal and ethically less problematic, scientifically deemed necessary trials. (Although they might have there own kinds of problems and scandals, like in studying [TGN1412](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/TGN1412)).

This can be shown also with more focus on medicine. It is not just yellow press word usage. Use the internal search engine of for example 
[Ärzteblatt](http://aerzteblatt.de), a newspaper for doctors.

- search for "Medikamentenversuch":

  - 0 hits
- search vor "Menschenversuche":

  - 43 hits, first is "Medizingeschichte: Der Nürnberger Ärzteprozess"
- search for "Versuche am Menschen":

  - 1.831 hits, first is "Erbkrankheiten: Neurologen stellen neue Leitlinie zu Chorea Huntington vor"

This empirical evidence of *Sprachpraxis* is quintessentially demonstrated in the following article: *[Geschichte der Medizin – Ansichten zur Ethik: Menschenversuch und Menschlichkeit](https://www.aerzteblatt.de/archiv/36609/Geschichte-der-Medizin-Ansichten-zur-Ethik-Menschenversuch-und-Menschlichkeit)*

> **What does “Medikamentenversuche” mean or refer to?**

**It means:** *Medikamentenversuche* can therefor be simple (human) drug trials, according to accepted standards, perfectly legal – and necessary. In theory, this is the original, broad, and intended meaning of the word by itself.

–or, more commonly in daily usage–

**It most often refers to:** *Medikamentenversuche* is overwhelmingly used to denote criminal, unethical "research", sometimes outright pseudoscientific experiments, with drugs, on humans. Illegal, improper, unethical "trials", medical scandals. In practice this is the context in which the word is most often found.
<sub>(If the the test subject isn't human, the term *Tierversuch* is used by similar critics and  proponents of *action against* for all kinds of unethical behaviour against animals.)</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Medikamentenversuche sind drug trials, in der Tat.

Wenn sich ein Text auf einen bestimmten solchen bezieht, dann liegt das am Kontext.

Die existierenden und erwähnten Alternativbezeichnungen wie *Studie* beweisen natürlich nicht, dass Medikamentenversuche nur für unethische Medikamentenversuche verwendet wird. Die Behauptung ist vollkommen absurd, wie auch das Kaffeesatzlesen in der Pluralform. Orangen stehen im Orangensaft auch im Plural, während der singuläre Apfel im Apfelsaft nicht impliziert, dass er aus einem einzigen Apfel produziert wurde. Es handelt sich hier um einen Fugenlaut, der eine geschmeidigere Aussprache erlaubt.

Informierte Zeitgenossen wissen, dass es auch Tiermedizin gibt, die natürlich nicht an Menschen versucht wird. Medikamentenversuche, die zuerst an Tieren, dann an Menschen durchgeführt werden, gibt es aber.

Tierversuche werden jedoch auch für Kosmetika veranstaltet und Menschenversuch kann man jeden Versuch am Menschen nennen - es müssen nicht Medikamente sein, die erprobt werden.

Ob ein Versuch ethisch ist hängt nicht vom Wort ab, sondern davon, ob der Patient umfassend und aufrichtig informiert wird, freiwillig am Test teilnehmen und das Risiko abwägen kann.

Wird gegen diese Richtlinien verstoßen bleibt der Medikamentenversuch ein solcher und die Studie eine solche.

Googlesuchen bringen zum Vorschein, was berichtet und was konsumiert wird. Unspektakuläre Studien, die ohne Skandal durchgeführt werden, finden einfach ein geringes Medienecho. Zu Messern findet man auch mehr Körperverletzungen als Fälle von Gemüseschneiden.

Comment: Ah! Du meinst also, der pagerank-Befund stellt keinen bevorzugten Kontext und daher überwiegend intendierte  Bedeutung dar? Die Reinheit der Lehre ist lobenswert. Ich weise darauf hin, dass die Beurteilung nach ethischen Richtlinien sich nicht an der ursprünglichen und durchaus richtigen Bedeutung des Wortes festmacht (und auch keine Aussage zu Forschungsethik selbst enthält). Umgekehrt zeigt sich, dass in der Sprachpraxis eine offenkundige Bedeutungsverengung durch die Mehrzahl der vorgefundenen Kontexte bedeutsam ist: "Wird gegen…" erst dann steht in der Zeitung -versuch, sonst eher nicht.

Comment: @LangLangC: Die intendierte Bedeutung ergibt sich nicht aus dem Pagerank, sondern aus dem Kontext. Die Sprachpraxis ist nicht das, was das Googleranking abbildet, sondern das Googleranking bildet Fundstellen sortiert nach einer Skala, in der Popularität die Hauptrolle spielt. Theoretisch können auch 10 Funde die Suchergebnisse dominieren, wenn diese untypische Wortverwendungen abbilden. Und gesprochene Sprache wird von Google gleich gar nicht erfasst. Überhaupt nicht.

Comment: Es geht glaube ich nicht darum, zu definieren, was *Medikamentenversuche* sind, sondern in welchem Kontext man diesen Begriff wählt.

Comment: @Takkat: Es geht darum, was das Wort bedeutet. Ein Biber ist ein Tier, auch wenn die Seiten das höchste Ranking haben, auf denen es um Justin Biber geht. Das Pageranking kann nicht als Ersatz für die Analyse des Kontexts verwendet werden. Im Supermarkt gibt es auch viel mehr Lebensmittel als Kosmetik, trotzdem würdest Du nicht die Seife essen, weil sie aus dem Supermarkt kommt, und damit die Wahrscheinlichkeit 90% ist, dass es was essbares ist.